# Change the message of a progressDialog in AsyncTask without altering doInBackgroud()

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have this `doInBackground`:

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params){
    return syncIn.syncData();       
}
```

This is the `asynctask` for downloading. The content of `doInBackground` can't be changed due to spaghetti code. I have a progress dialog going on while the task does its thing. Is there a way to use `onProgressUpdate()` and other methods to change the dialog message dynamically, without touching the `doInBackground`?

So far, I created a static string in the `async` class, which is altered by various methods from `syncData()`. How to update the dialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You have to call `publishProgress()` from within `doInBackground()` in order to get `onProgressUpdate()` to be called.

Answer (score 2):

in Async Task onProgressUpdate method is Automatically call once the progress of Download will update but for this you must required to publish this Event in doinBackground method.so I think without modifying doInBackround() it's not possible.you must need to call publishProgress() method in doInBackground() method.

I am having one Code Snippet to do this I Hope it's Helping you but in this you must be call publishProgress() method in doInbackground() method.

```
 public YourClassConstructor(Context context)
{
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Your Message");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
}
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
 progressDialog.setMessage("Your Message "+progress);
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params){
    publishProgress(DOWNLOAD PROGRESS VALUE);

    return syncIn.syncData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answers.

Ended up writing a method that takes a String from the sub methods in syncData() and uses publishProgress(), so technically, doInBackground() was calling  publishProgress().

Hope this helps.